# How do I get my delete button to delete one row of data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What I am doing wrong?
I am trying to get the delete button to delete one person data.

```
<li v-for="(person,index) in persons">
  <span v-for="value in person"> {{ value }} </span>
  
</li>
 <button @click.native="deleteQuote">
  Delete
  </button>
```

```
  data: {
    ingredients: ['meat', 'fruit', 'salad'],
    persons: [
    {name: 'Max', age: 27, color: 'red'},
    {name: 'Mit', age: 47, color: 'red'},
    {name: 'Foo', age: 37, color: 'red'},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    deleteQuote: function(person) {
        this.persons.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: did you try out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put button element inside the `li` tag and remove the `native` modifier and pass the `index` as a parameter to the `deleteQuote` method:

```
<li v-for="(person,index) in persons">
  <span v-for="value in person"> {{ value }} </span>
   <button @click="deleteQuote(index)">
      Delete
  </button>
</li>
```

the method should be defined with `index` as a parameter :

```
  methods: {
    deleteQuote: function(index) {
        this.persons.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```